# Can't obtain Google Search suggestion API

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, autosuggest, search-suggestion

Trying to use an xmlHTTPrequest to get search suggestions but I am having trouble getting access.

The link is: http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=ja&q=keyword
It loads fine when put into the address bar.

I have already written a code to get xml files from a Rakuten API which works. I tried using it with this URL instead but it fails to get any information.

This is the error in Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=ja&q=keyword. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This is the xml part of the code used.

```
var getURL="http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=ja&q=keyword";
xmlhttp.open("GET",getURL,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

What is needed to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: why suggestqueries.google.com ..? when u can use google.com/complete/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it in a page served by a web server instead of from a local file.